# Is WiFi calling supported on ios 8 on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi-calling

I have an iPhone 5, and I don't have good reception at home, so I was hoping to use wifi calling after upgrading to ios 8, but I can't find an option to enable it.  BTW I'm with T-Mobile carrier.

Comment: Could be wrong, hence comment, but isn't wifi calling (VOLTE) an iphone 6 thing, not an iOS8 thing?

Comment: UPDATE: I found that they intentionally removed the feature from iphone5, it worked on ios8 beta releases.  Source: http://www.imore.com/why-doesnt-wi-fi-calling-work-iphone-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the major WiFi-calling provider [T-Mobile](http://newsroom.t-mobile.com/news/t-mobile-launches-un-carrier-7.htm) following Apple phones are [compatible](http://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phones/wi-fi-calling.html):

iPhone 5c

iPhone 5s

and iPhone 6 (+)

Answer (score 3):

As of right now, it is only available on 5c, 5s, and 6.

Whether or not this is intentional is unsure since t-mobile themselves thought it would be available for the 5 as well.  We will have to wait for some kind of update for iPhone 5

Comment: Here is a part of my conversation with TMobile online  that they think it's suppose to work, For it being 5c 5s and 6,  it is available on my devices for these, not including the 6, I get this hopefully today, I am assuming that has it though, (not enough room to post full chat)


You: is the wifi calling suppose to work on iPhone 5
ChristinaG: Yes, once the operating system is updated to iOS8.
You: ok thank you I guess I will contact back in two hours
ChristinaG: I appreciate your patience, Anthony. Did I miss anything from you today?
You: nope

Answer (score 0):

No, according to [Apple's support document on the topic](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203032) the iPhone 5c is the minimum model of iPhone that supports Wi-Fi calling.